# Getting data from php element after a click and using them to create another section in the same page

Tags: javascript, php, html

this is a piece of my code from a webpage that I'm doing:

```
echo "<div  class='card'>
        <div onclick='on()' class='card-body'>
            <h5 class='card-title' >".$row["name"]."</h5>
            <p class='card-text' >".$row["comment"]."</p>
         </div>
      </div>";
```

With this code (and other that I don't write here) I created a sequence of cards with different information (name, comment). When a user clicks on one of these cards I would like to create an overlay section that **maximize the information reported in the clicked card.** So I would like to **retrieve info** (name and comment) **from the clicked card** and then **write them into the piece of code below** (in the same page).

```
<div id="overlay" onclick="off()">
    <!-- info from the card that the user clicked -->                   
</div>
```

I don't have an idea on how to do it.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: PHP cannot react to user clicks, you will need javascript.  The 'old fashioned' way would be to create a PHP endpoint returning (only) the HTML fragment you want to insert (i.e. no page surround, header, nav, etc) and then fetch it with js and stick it in the DOM.  The 'new fangled' way would involve your PHP serving 'raw data' in (e.g.) json format and using a js framework to handle the whole render-to-HTML aspect.  You'll probably find the 'old fashioned' way easier to learn and implement iteratively on top of your current work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @stevekeiretsu I understand. As he wrote

> The 'new fangled' way would involve your PHP serving 'raw data' in (e.g.) json format and using a js framework to handle the whole render-to-HTML aspect.

I used this technique and it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
php echo

    <div  class='card'>
        <div onclick='on('card_id_05')' class='card-body'>
            <h5 class='card-title' >".$row["name"]."</h5>
            <p class='card-text' >".$row["comment"]."</p>
        </div>
    </div>  

 //somewhere else

php echo 
    function on(var card_id) 
    {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
         {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) 
                 {
                    document.getElementById("overlay").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                 }
          };
      xhttp.open("GET", "overlay.php?&cardId = "+card_id, true);
      xhttp.send();
    }


    function off()
    {
        document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
    }


//https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp
```